# Desativar drag da página em um dispositivo móvel

Tags: html, front-end

Estou desenvolvendo uma página onde temos um `<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5">`. Sempre que tenho arrastar esse `input`, caso eu erre o dedo, acabo que sem querer arrastando a página completa. Ela vai pro lado e volta.

Tem como desativar esse `Drag` da página?

Comment: Phellipe, é isto que procura? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8782202/2256325

Comment: provavelmente, ainda não testei. Assim que testar posto os resultados.

Comment: @PhellipeLins conseguiu resolver? Poste uma resposta do que fez para ajudar outras pessoas no futuro.

Comment: Não consegui. Acabei desistindo até que alguém venha a entender e responder. Estou muito atarefado, sem tempo pra buscar pela resposta.

Comment: A resposta não foi útil? explique melhor seu problema para que eu possa te ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Isto é feito em nível de sistema operacional, segue o link para você conferir.

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Porém tem uma solução interessante que é:

Assim que você entrar na sua página pode setar o histórico para ela mesma.

Exemplo:

```
document.location.hash = "http://www.meusite.com.br/";
```

pode fazer um teste usando:

```
window.history.back()
```